# Как проверить существует ли число в массиве

Tags: php, html

Выводятся массивы диапазона даты из БД

```
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $datein=$row["datein"];
    $dateout=$row["dateout"];
    $days = range(strtotime($datein), strtotime($dateout), (24*60*60));
    }
```

Имеется таблица с колонками дней(15 дней).
[image: таблица]
Как сделать, чтобы ячейки закрашивались красным цветом если этот день имеется в любом массиве диапазона даты.
Например: Если в диапазоне даты имеется 20.01.2019 то в колонке "20 Jan 2019" закрасилась ячейка.
Очень долго сижу делаю, но ничего не получается.

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
$datein=$row["datein"];
$dateout=$row["dateout"];
for($i=0; $i<15; $i++) {

$date = strtotime("+$i day");
$datein = strtotime("$datein");
$dateout = strtotime("$dateout");

$yd = date("Y", $date);
$md = date("m", $date);
$dd = date("d", $date);
$complexd = "$yd$md$dd";
$complexd = strtotime("$complexd");

$yi = date("Y", $datein);
$mi = date("m", $datein);
$di = date("d", $datein);
$complexi = "$yi$mi$di";
$complexi = strtotime("$complexi");

$yo = date("Y", $dateout);
$mo = date("m", $dateout);
$do = date("d", $dateout);
$complexo = "$yo$mo$do";
$complexo = strtotime("$complexo");

if($complexd >= $complexi && $date <= $complexo) {$color = $red;} 
if ($complexd < $complexi) {$color = $green;}
if ($complexd > $complexo) {$color = $green;}
      echo'<td class="blend" style="background-color:'.$color.';"></td>';
            } }
```

Выводится только из первого массива, а остальные не видит.

Comment: in_array не пробовали?

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю сделать сначала массив из всех используемых дней, а потом уж строить табличку проверяя есть ли ключ а массиве $data

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $period = new DatePeriod(
         new DateTime('2010-10-01'), #$row["datein"];
         new DateInterval('P1D'),
         new DateTime('2010-10-05')  #$row["dateout"];
    );

    foreach ($period as $key => $value) {
        $date[$value->format('Y-m-d')]=true; # массив можно наполнить например событиями/мероприятиями   
    }
}
print_r($date);
```